# Hide element when scrolling outside it

Tags: javascript

I use this code to hide block when user scrolling the page. How can i hide block only when scrolling outside it.

```
$('html, body').bind('scroll',function (e) {
 var container = $("CONTAINER SELECTOR");
 if (container.has(e.target).length === 0){
  container.hide();
 }
});
```

This is my html

```
<div class="parent_block">
 <div class="menu-button">
  <img src="/img.svg" />
 </div>
 <div class="toggled_block">
  <nav><a href="/">Home</a></nav>
 </div>
</div>
<script>
 $(".menu-button").click(function() {
  $('.toggled_block').toggle();
 });
 $(document).on('click', function(e) {
  if (!$(e.target).closest(".parent_block").length) {
  $('.toggled_block').hide(); 
 }
 e.stopPropagation();
});
$(document).bind('scroll',function (e) {
 var container = $(".toggled_block");
 if (container.has(e.target).length === 0){
  container.hide();
 }
});
```

Comment: Could you share you html

Comment: @MunkhdelgerTumenbayar , edited. Here is my html/